# Can I have multiple templates for a content type under "New Documents"?

Tags: content-type, document-template

I am a new SharePoint 2010 user. I have a situation where I need to add templates to a sharepoint library, so when a user selects "New Document" a list of templates displays.  Multiple templates have been developed for each type of document-example:There is an Announcement template available in MSWord, Outlook, and PowerPoint. Users will pick their template based upon the best delivery method. There are 12 other types of content/documents that have multiple templates, so the list is too long to display as a straight dropdown from "New Document". Is there a way to have the different templates display when the user hovers over or clicks on the template?  Example:  User clicks or hovers over Announcement and Outlook, MSWord, and PowerPoint display?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to do this out-of-the-box. You have to develop a solution for this.

But there is already an open source project called **[Template Hub for SharePoint](http://templatehub.codeplex.com/)** on codeplex existing for this purpose. It is well documented and available for SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013.

Have a look at this. Maybe this fits your requirements.